# Bokeh plots not displaying after successful AJAX request and div HTML update

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, bokeh

I have a Flask view that returns the div, script tuple from components call. This is returned as a response to a JQuery-generated GET request, where, upon success, I select the corresponding plot div and plot script divs (in that order) and update their inner HTML as seen on many examples. Nothing breaks. In fact, the inner HTML updates are successful, as verified by element inspection, but nothing gets updated visually. Any thoughts?

In my JQuery call:

```
`$.get(route, function(response){
    $('#plot_div').html(response.div)
    $('#plot_script').html(response.script)
 });`
```

In my Flask view:

```
`script, div = components(row(children=plot_list))
return jsonify(div=div, script=script)`
```